# Specify SOCKS Proxy For NightmareJS?

Tags: javascript, proxy, electron, socks, nightmare

I'm able to set an HTTP proxy just fine for NightmareJS but how do I specify the type (http/socks5/socks4)? Here's the code I use to set an HTTP proxy:

```
const nightmare = Nightmare({
            show:true,
            switches: {
                'proxy-server': proxyHost + ':' + proxyPort,
                'ignore-certificate-errors': true
            },
            waitTimeout: 400000
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the type of the proxy via the URI scheme: 
**`socks5://`**

```
const nightmare = Nightmare({
    switches: {
        'proxy-server': 'socks5://' + proxyHost + ':' + proxyPort,
    },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found it last night. Will accept. Thanks.